# Fail to add elements in a list

Tags: r

I want to create the following list

```
myList[[1]][1] 10
myList[[1]][2] 20
myList[[1]][3] 30 40
```

So I write the following code but it seems that I am doing it wrong:

```
myList <- vector(mode = "list")
myList[[length(myList)+1]] <- 10
# myList[[length(myList)+1]][1] <- 10 # it seems more reasonable, but it does not work either
myList[[length(myList)]][2] <- 20
myList[[length(myList)]][3] <- c(30, 40)
print(myList)
```

Should the third element myList[[1]][3] be a list too ?

Comment: How about `list(list(10, 20, c(30, 40))`

Comment: I want to add elements in the list interactively. That's why I use the length function.

Comment: You can use `c()` on a list too, like `c(list(10), list(20))`, so you really never need to use the length.  I'll write something up for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create this list:

```
myList[[1]][1] 10
myList[[1]][2] 20
myList[[1]][3] 30 40
```

This would imply that `myList[[1]]` would be equal to:

```
[1] 10
[2] 20
[3] 30 40
```

Which is not an acceptable variable in R, since you are implying that element 3 of the vector is a vector itself.

However, this is:

```
[[1]]
[1]   10
[[2]] 
[1]   20
[[3]] 
[1]   30 40
```

So you can do:

```
myList = list()
myList = c(myList, 10)
myList = c(myList, 20)
myList = c(myList, list(c(30, 40)))
```

Which results in

```
> myList
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 20

[[3]]
[1] 30 40
```